# Represent full globe in Oracle Spatial

Tags: well-known-text, oracle-spatial

In SQL Server 2012 I can do this:

```
-- Construct a new FullGlobe object (a WGS84 ellipsoid)
DECLARE @Earth geography = 'FULLGLOBE'

-- Calculate the area of the earth
SELECT PlanetArea = @Earth.STArea()
```

Is there a similar construct in Oracle Spatial?

Alternatively what would be the best way to represent the entire earth in an 8307/4326 SRID?

Is there anything in the WKT standard that speaks to this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are querying data, you could use an optimized rectangle.  But, the [Oracle Spatial documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_cs_concepts.htm#CIHHGHFH) advises against using these geometries from anything other then query windows.

```
sdo_geometry(2003, 8307, null, 
    sdo_elem_info_array(1,1003,3), 
    sdo_ordinate_array(-180,-90,180,90))
```

If need to store the geometry, I would use a multipart polygon that splits the world into three or more parts.  In Oracle spatial, you can't create a geometry that is equal to or greater than half the world's surface.  You could use four squares:

```
sdo_geometry(2003, 8307, null, 
    sdo_elem_info_array(1,1003,1,11,1003,1,21,1003,1,31,1003,1), 
    sdo_ordinate_array( -180,-90,0,-90,0,0,-180,0,-180,-90,
                        -180,0,0,0,0,90,-180,90,-180,0,
                        0,-90,180,-90,180,0,0,0,0,-90,
                        0,0,180,0,180,90,0,90,0,0))
```

Or triangles with a geographic coordinate system (because Oracle Spatial considers the curvature):

```
sdo_geometry(2003, 8307, null, 
    sdo_elem_info_array(1,1003,1,9,1003,1,17,1003,1,25,1003,1), 
    sdo_ordinate_array( -180,-90,0,0,-180,0,-180,-90,
                        -180,0,0,0,0,90,-180,0,
                        0,-90,180,0,0,0,0,-90,
                        0,0,180,0,180,90,0,0)),0.05)
```